# How to add democracy pallet as a substrate frame pallet

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

i am clone substrate node template from this command
"git clone --branch latest --depth 1 [https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template"](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template%22)

add pallet_democracy in runtime/cargo.toml

then run below command
"cargo check -p node-template-runtime"

i will get below error
error: failed to select a version for `syn`.
... required by package `frame-support-procedural v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support-procedural` of package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support` of package `frame-benchmarking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking` of package `pallet-democracy v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `pallet-democracy` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/amit/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/amit/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^1.0.98` are: 1.0.98

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

previously selected package `syn v1.0.95`
... which satisfies dependency `syn = "^1.0.84"` (locked to 1.0.95) of package `async-trait v0.1.53`
... which satisfies dependency `async-trait = "^0.1"` (locked to 0.1.53) of package `jsonrpsee-core v0.13.1`
... which satisfies dependency `jsonrpsee-core = "^0.13.1"` (locked to 0.13.1) of package `jsonrpsee v0.13.1`
... which satisfies dependency `jsonrpsee = "^0.13.0"` (locked to 0.13.1) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/amit/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template/node)`

failed to select a version for `syn` which could resolve this conflict

How to solve it!!

Comment: Democracy pallet is not so simple to integrate as it depends on other pallets as well. You can start by looking how it is configured here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6f652840cc78629ac149bf36d23ab34345c65331/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1597

Comment: As suggested [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/415#issuecomment-1188093567), try running `cargo update -p syn:1.0.95`

Answer (score 2):

Usually this happens when you have some dependency version conflicts in your runtime Cargo.toml and pallet's Cargo.toml.

Compare all of the Cargo.toml in your project and compare all the versions of each dependencies in every place. it should be similar.

for example,

in runtime if you're using this
frame-election-provider-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "**polkadot-v0.9.24**"  }

and in your pallet if you are using different branch like this
frame-election-provider-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "**polkadot-v0.9.18**"  }

you will get this error.  hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try the process described in the tutorials here: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/add-a-pallet/

Comment: I am following above link but after adding pallet-democracy in the runtime i get above error

Answer (score 0):

i am follow above tutorial and add pallet-democracy in the runtime/cargo.toml
then run below command "cargo check -p node-template-runtime"

but i will get below error

error: failed to select a version for `syn`.
... required by package `frame-support-procedural v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support-procedural` of package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support` of package `frame-benchmarking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking` of package `pallet-democracy v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
... which satisfies git dependency `pallet-democracy` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/amit/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/amit/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^1.0.98` are: 1.0.98

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

previously selected package `syn v1.0.95`
... which satisfies dependency `syn = "^1.0.84"` (locked to 1.0.95) of package `async-trait v0.1.53`
... which satisfies dependency `async-trait = "^0.1"` (locked to 0.1.53) of package `jsonrpsee-core v0.13.1`
... which satisfies dependency `jsonrpsee-core = "^0.13.1"` (locked to 0.13.1) of package `jsonrpsee v0.13.1`
... which satisfies dependency `jsonrpsee = "^0.13.0"` (locked to 0.13.1) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/amit/Substrate/New/substrate-node-template/node)`

failed to select a version for `syn` which could resolve this conflict

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Cargo.lock** -> search **name = "syn"** -> remove **checksum** -> set **version = "1.0.96"** (with branch ="polkadot-v0.9.24) -> cargo build --release

With another branch, you should choose **"syn"** version properly